# Embed a function from another file into a Python Class

Tags: python, class

I have some `commonfunctions` that I reuse as methods of different classes. I store these function in a commonfunctions.py file inside my module directory. I would like to embed the functions inside the class where I need it, and being able to modify the attributes of the classes. I have done some attempts but none of them is practical. I was wondering what is the best approach to do that.

commonfunctions.py

```
def mycommonfun(self,myarg):
    self.target = myarg+3

class mydummyclass(object):
    def mycommonfun(self,myarg):
        self.target = myarg+3
```

mainfile.py

```
import commonfunctions

class A(anotherclass):
   def __init__(self):
     self.target = None
   # not working
   commonfunctions.mycommonfun
class B(anotherclass):
   def __init__(self):
     self.target = None
     # I can't modify self.target
     self.mycommonfun = commonfunctions.mycommonfun
class C(anotherclass):
    # it works but it hides all the docstring
    def mycommonfun(self,myarg):
        commonfunctions.mycommonfun(self,myarg)

class D(anotherclas,commonfunctions.mydummyclass):
    pass #it works not sure why I have problem with hinting of the arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is inherit other class methods.

commonfunction.py

```
class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target

    def some_function(self, n):
        self.target = 3 + n
```

mainfile.py

```
from commonfunction import ParentClass


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, target):
        super().__init__(target)


child = ChildClass(5) # self.target = 5
child.some_function(5) # self.target = 3 + 5 = 8
```